# Expected Value of the Difference between 2 Dice

Tags: probability, puzzle, recreational-mathematics, dice

> What is the expected value of the absolute difference between 2 N
>   faced dice? What about the difference between 2 dice one with N faces
>   and one with M faces?

While finding the expected value of 2 random variable sums or differences are simple enough, how do you deal with absolute value of differences?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried listing all the possibilities in some simple cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split into cases.

For the first,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{|i-j|}{n^2} = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \frac{i-j}{n^2} = \frac{n^2-1}{3n}$$

For the second, if $n < m$, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{|i-j|}{nm} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \frac{i-j}{nm} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=i}^m \frac{j-i}{nm} = \frac{2 n^2 - 3 n m + 3 m^2  - 2}{6m}$$

Comment: Is it surprising that the second formula is so unsymmetric in $m$ and $n$, with $m$ but not $n$ in the denominator?

Comment: Maybe it would be if I could figure out what $n=0$ would mean.